# Python: How to specify function return type in a mixin method

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I'm trying to accurately annotate the type of return from a mixin method.

Minimal example below:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict, Protocol

class HasStore(Protocol):
    store: dict


class StoreGetMixin:
    def __getitem__(self: HasStore, key: str):  # what to put in -> type?
        return self.store[key]


@dataclass
class ThingOne:
    size: int


@dataclass
class ThingTwo:
    name: str


@dataclass
class Ones(StoreGetMixin):
    store: Dict[str, ThingOne] = field(default_factory=dict)


@dataclass
class Twos(StoreGetMixin):
    store: Dict[str, ThingTwo] = field(default_factory=dict)


ones = Ones()
ones.store = {"a": ThingOne(1), "b": ThingOne(2)}
one = ones["a"]  # <- this should be typed as a ThingOne

twos = Twos()
twos.store = {"a": ThingTwo("one"), "b": ThingTwo("two")}
two = twos["a"]  # <- this should be typed as a ThingTwo
```

So I'm trying to write a reusable mixin that can access the `store` dictionary in various dataclasses. But I don't know how to tell the `__getitem__` method what type it is returning.

I've seen examples of typing `self` but i need to type `self.store` in this case. mypy can see the type of `self.store` as `dict` (I assume this comes from `HasStore`) but it doesn't know the key or value types.

Is this possible?

Do I need to annotate the `HasStore` protocol's `store` better? I tried, eg, `dict[str, T]` but I couldn't make it work because `T` isn't instantiated if used like that.

The reason I'm doing this is to use Mashumaro to serialise my dataclasses into JSON and I couldn't figure out how to store a plain dictionary keyed off a `str` without making a single attribute in a dataclass called `store`. So there are a few of these and they are all have a `dict` called `store` so I thought I'd use `collections.abc.MutableMapping` to allow me to access `store` via a subscript, eg, `twos["a"]`. Therefore, I wrote the mixin to do this but it's a pity to lose all the types if I don't need to.

Thanks heaps for any pointers :)

Answer (score 1):

A Generic Protocol should work (doc here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-protocols):

```
T = TypeVar('T')


class HasStore(Protocol[T]):
    store: Dict[str, T]


class StoreGetMixin(HasStore[T]):

    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> T:  # what to put in -> type?
        return self.store[key]


@dataclass
class ThingOne:
    size: int


@dataclass
class ThingTwo:
    name: str


@dataclass
class Ones(StoreGetMixin[ThingOne]):
    store: Dict[str, ThingOne] = field(default_factory=dict)


@dataclass
class Twos(StoreGetMixin[ThingTwo]):
    store: Dict[str, ThingTwo] = field(default_factory=dict)


ones = Ones()
ones.store = {"a": ThingOne(1), "b": ThingOne(2)}
one = ones["a"]  # <- this should be typed as a ThingOne
reveal_type(one)
twos = Twos()
twos.store = {"a": ThingTwo("one"), "b": ThingTwo("two")}
two = twos["a"]  # <- this should be typed as a ThingTwo
reveal_type(two)
```

output is:

```
note: Revealed type is 'experiment.ThingOne*'
note: Revealed type is 'experiment.ThingTwo*'
```

Comment: oh nice thank you! I see how i need to instantiate the type vars in the class definition. I didn't really understand that before.
However, is there a way to get that ThingOne/ThingTwo type from the store variable itself. The superclass knows which one it is when it's defined.
In any case, your changes have made it work now and also fixed some `ones["a"] = ...` type error two, as i assume it now knows what is supposed to be put in that dict.